# Java. Try to deserialize if file exists. Otherwise just don't

Tags: java, serialization, try-catch, filenotfoundexception

I am using Serialization to get persistent storage for my library managing app (I know it is not the right way, but it's the way my professor wants it).

I am using the following code inside my main();

```
    controlador.getBiblioteca().getGestorMaterial().setListaLibros((Modelo.ColeccionLibros) controlador.getSerializador().abrirArchivo("libros.dat"));
```

My Serializador class has the `abrirArchivo("FileName.dat")` function (openFile in English).

That function looks like this:

```
public Object abrirArchivo(String nombreDelArchivo) {
    Object retorno = null;
    try {
        lectorArchivos = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(
                nombreDelArchivo));
        retorno = lectorArchivos.readObject();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return retorno;
}
```

Now I am trying to check if the program gets a FileNotFoundException for any of the files. If it does, it should just not deserialize the file and go for the next one: that would just mean there is no book in my library yet.

The problem is, if the line runs, it seems to set my book list using `setListaLibros()` to null. And whenever I try to access that list, i get a NullPointerException. The list was already initialized as an empty list though, so I just need to leave it alone as long as the "libros.dat" file is not found.

What is the right way to get that done?

Comment: Hint: those fluent calls where you do one call after other ... try to not do that.  Instead read about "Law of Demeter" and understand that its really bad if you get something to get something to get something to do something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a line before this: `controlador.getBiblioteca().getGestorMaterial().setListaLibros((Modelo.ColeccionLibros) controlador.getSerializador().abrirArchivo("libros.dat"));` which checks if the file exists. If it does not, then it prompts the user. This way, the user *knows* something went wrong and can act accordingly.

Alternatively, you can make a change in your `setListLibros` method wherein, if the argument passed is `null`, then you do not do any assignment.

Personally, I would go with the first option.

As a side note, please break down your code, something like so: `controlador.getBiblioteca().getGestorMaterial().setListaLibros((Modelo.ColeccionLibros) controlador.getSerializador().abrirArchivo("libros.dat"))` can get hard to read and debug.

Comment: I actually think the second option might me the right solution. I'll try that as soon as I am back at my computer. Thank you for the breaking down the code idea. I did also struggle to read my line a couple of days after writing it. I'll look into that too.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if I understand the problem well. However, as I can see in your code, when an exception FileNotFoundException happens, "retorno" will keep null. That's the reason why you get setListaLibros(null).
And then your list will became null. If you don't want that behavior, you should initialize "retorno" with an empty list instead of null.

Comment: I use that function to deserialize objects of type Object and that is what it returns. Then I get them to be lists of books (casting), or other kind of objects. If I want retorno to be a list, it cannot be an object anymore, and I will lose my casting possibilities.

Comment: In this case, you should initialize retorno with something that will make sense to be passed to setListaLibros and it will then create an empty list from that. This design is common known as "Null Object Design Pattern". I suggest you to google it, so you can think of a appropriate design.

Answer (score 1):

There is an aspect that the other answers are not mentioning: why are there no serialized objects when your library is empty?!

What I mean is: you could distinguish between "program runs the first time" (and obviously no serialized data exists) or "program ran before; and thus it fully configures itself from serialized data.

Meaning: "being empty" can be a valid state of a library, too. So another option would be to not use a "special value" (aka "no file with data") to represent that information ... but (de)serialize an empty list.

Comment: That sounds good, the problem is, I would have to ship also empty files and tell the professor to store them where he stores the project before running it. That was my first solution, but I would like to be able to run the program without those files.

Comment: No, you would not have to hand out "empty" files. Your application creates them the first time it starts up!

Comment: how do you make the app now if it is the first time to run? although I went for the one suggested by npinti, I actually like this way of doing it.

Comment: Actually ... good point. Probably something along those lines: when the program starts, it checks if there are files with deserialized objects. If not, it immediately creates ones for "empty". But probably this needs more thinking. I will sleep over it; and maybe I have an idea next week ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the file exist like:

```java
String fileName;
File f1 = new File(fileName);
if (f1.exists()) {
//Do the work
}
```